# C++ inheritance for character class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have an assignment to recreate a game. I have to implement a list of characters. For example, I have the `Character` class which has only the name of the character.

Now, I need to create a Character `Warrior` who is an enemy in the game. Do I need to implement my inheritance like this: `Character --> Enemy --> Warrior` when my enemy class basically has no attributes. It's more of a classification than anything.

Is there a way to have an `Enemy` and a `Warrior` defined in the same class, where `Warrior` is of type `Enemy`, which is of type `Character`? There are going to be more enemies, but only one `Warrior`.

Thanks

Comment: Inheritance is not the answer to every problem. I would have a single character class with attributes that specify the properties of the character. The kind of class hierarchy you are considering is more common in C++ text books than in production code.

Comment: We don't have enough information for this, and we'll probably never have. This is a matter of taste. Is it possible for a player (either a human one or an artificial intelligence) to play a `Warrior`? Then the classification as `Enemy` is wrong. Is there really a need for `Enemy`? Probably not. Instead make a `ControllableCharacter` or something similar, which can be controlled by a human or a character. Good/bad parent classes which provide nothing but additional information make code often only more complicated.

Answer (score 4):

You say the enemy class has basically no attributes.

That's the case now, but one reason for using an Enemy class and inheritance is that it better anticipates unknown future needs of the code by building in (nearly) transparent flexibility now.

You could certainly make a type for the Enemy class, but as you add more enemies, you may find that this solution requires more and more code in the form of `switch` statements and `if` clauses to check on the type.

Answer (score 2):

If all Warriors are Enemies, and have all the properties of an enemy, then yes, it makes sense to have Warrior be a subclass of Enemy.

As some of the comments have pointed out, having a complicated inheritance chain is problematic and asymptomatic of poor program architecture.

> Is there a way to have an Enemy and a Warrior defined in the same class, where Warrior is of type Enemy, which is of type Character?

In the inheritance chain we've discussed, Warrior is a Type of Enemy which is a Type of Character.

I think you might be confusing a class with the file that defines it. You can't define a class that has two types. You can define multiple classes inside a single .h and implement them inside a single cpp file, but style-wise, it's better to define a single class in a single .h/.cpp pair.